# Как сделать размер окна фиксированным в Python eel?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникла необходимость написать приложение на python с использованием библиотеки eel, но возникла проблема: нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог изменять размер окна.
Как это реализовать?

**Пример тестового кода:**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import eel


eel.init("web")  # EEL initialization


@eel.expose
def binary(number):
    """This function converts the entered number from the decimal system to binary"""
    return bin(int(number)).replace("0b", "")


eel.start("main.html", size=(700, 400))  # Starting the App
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтоб пользователь не мог изменять размер окна, нужно добавить в проект js код, в котором размер окна будет сбрасываться при попытке его изменить.

попробуйте

```
window.resizable = false
```

Comment: Добрый день. Вот JS код: https://pastebin.com/jigxhGqd  
Можете подсказать, как конкретно встроить сюда ваш пример кода?

Comment: Фиксировать окно не получиться! (Пример) Вместо этого создайте браузер (pyqt5) [https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-browser/] Пример создания. И как получается  вы запускаете сначала eel файл с кодом (без выбора браузера) и потом второй файл с pyqt5 (там окно должно быть зафиксировано). Это пример, вместо pyqt5 можно использовать еще что то...